# Show progress image while executing JSF managed bean action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My question kind of applies to Prime Faces progress bar but any vanilla jsf implementations(using jquery) would be helpful.  My problem is when I start the long mysql query I also render the progress bar.  The problem is it starts it's progress after the data query is complete.  I'm guessing because the render phase isn't applied until the back end stuff is complete.  Would I need to start the progress bar in another thread?

The progress bar doesn't necessarily have to show where the query is at(if that is even possible).  I really just want to show the application "thinking".  Maybe with some text or an animated gif.  Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

This is what I have.

```
     <p:ajaxStatus>
            <f:facet name="start">
                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajax-loader-bar.gif" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="complete">
                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajax-loader-bar-still.gif" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="default">
                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajax-loader-bar-still.gif" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:ajaxStatus>
```

The request is not ajax.

```
  <p:commandButton value="Yes" update="growl"  onclick="confirmation.hide()"
                             action="#{viewLines.downloadFile}" ajax="false" />
```

The method behind it is.

```
    public void downloadFile() {

    if (selectedPkgLine != null) {

        ExcelSheet excelSheet = new ExcelSheet();
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

        String pkgLineName = StringUtils.removeSpaces(StringUtils.stripGarbage(selectedPkgLine.getShortname()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(pkgLineName);
        builder.append(".xls");

        externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + builder.toString());

        try {
            excelSheet.writeExcelSheet(this, externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());
        } catch (WriteException ex) {
            FacesUtils.addFatalMessage(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            FacesUtils.addErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            FacesUtils.addErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        }

        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } else {
        submitDisabled = true;
        FacesUtils.addErrorMessage("No packaging line was selected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab some animated icon from http://ajaxload.info, include it in your page with CSS `display: none;` and use JavaScript to make it `display: block;` during onclick:

```
<h:commandButton onclick="document.getElementById('progress').style.display='block'" />
<img id="progress" src="progress.gif" style="display:none" />
```

Or if you prefer jQuery (which is already part of PrimeFaces):

```
<h:commandButton onclick="$('#progress').show()" />
<img id="progress" src="progress.gif" style="display:none" />
```

This however only works fine with synchronous requests. Since you're using PrimeFaces, I'd suggest to use [`p:ajaxStatus`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprAjaxStatus.jsf) instead since it will take asynchronous (ajax) requests into account. Just put this piece of code anywhere in the template, you need only one of it. It will work for every `<p:commandButton>` and `<p:commandLink>` **without** `ajax="false"` and the `<p:ajax>`.

```
<img id="progress" src="progress.gif" style="display:none" />
<p:ajaxStatus>
    <f:facet name="start"><h:graphicImage value="progress.gif" /></f:facet>
    <f:facet name="success"><h:outputText value="" /></f:facet>
    <f:facet name="error">An error has occurred!</f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

If you want to intercept on the standard JSF `<f:ajax>`, then use `<f:ajax onevent>` instead.

```
<h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax onevent="progressListener" />
</h:commandButton>
<img id="progress" src="progress.gif" style="display:none" />
```

With this JavaScript function:

```
function progressListener(data) {
    document.getElementById("progress").style.display = (status == "begin") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: That's funny you say that because that's exactly what I have.  While that works with filtering and ajax events, it doesn't move at all when I'm doing mysql queries.

Comment: Maybe you pressed `Esc` or certain key combo in browser which stops all animated gifs. Or in case of `p:ajaxStatus`, it was not an ajax request at all.

Comment: It's not an ajax request.  Which brings me back to the whole Excel thing if you remember.

My action has to be false because I have to have the user download a file.  The xls file is generated on the fly using JXL and Mysql.  How would I get around that?  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: That's already answered in 1st part of my answer. Display it using JS/jQuery during onclick. Or if you want to reuse the existing loading `<h:graphicImage>`, give it an `id` and use it instead.

Comment: I start to realize that you've only a problem left with stopping the progress gif. In that case I don't see another option than storing the file in a temp location on disk and conditionally render a `<script>window.open()</script>` on that URL when the (ajax!) bean action is finished.

Comment: Hey Balus.  I've been thinking about this too. It seems that method is the only way to do it.  :(.  There is no other way to submit the file for download and have ajax working right?

This doesn't give you any ideas does it?
http://particletree.com/notebook/ajax-file-download-or-not/

Comment: That's in the same line as conditionally rendering a `window.open()`: conditionally submitting a form which points to the URL of the temp file. I think it's a bit better since there may exist some mad popup blockers.

Comment: Ok I think that's what I'm going to go with then.  How should I implement the temp folder/file?  Should I just delete the file after they download it or is there a better way to go about this.

Comment: You could use `File.createTempFile("name", ".ext")` for this. And just delete after last byte is written, yes.

Comment: I thought about that but then the file wouldn't be available for download.

Comment: Use a servlet to stream the bytes. Or if the WAR is expanded and writable, write it in public webcontent instead. Assuming that you've a `/temp` folder in there, `File.createTempFile("name", ".ext", externalContext.getRealPath("/temp"))`. Then you can use a direct URL like `window.location='temp/#{bean.file.name}';`

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your help Balus again.  I was able to implement it with temp file and using the file down loader built into prime faces.  I am then generating a commandLink to that file.  This allows me to show progress on the page using the ajax loader in prime faces.  The only problem is now I am generating lots of temp files in my web application.  Obviously the deleteOnExit will not work in this case.  Do you have any suggestions.  I was a little confused on your "use a servlet to stream the bytes".  I think you mean after all the headers we're sent I could delete the file.

Comment: With a servlet, you've got full control over the `File` yourself. You could just delete it after the last byte is been written to the response. In your new case, you could also consider to store a handle of the file in some map or object in the session scope and then use `HttpSessionListener` or `HttpSessionBindingListener` to delete the file(s) when the session is destroyed.

Comment: Hey Balus.  Thanks for all the help on this.  I learned a lot.  I have decided to revert back to the old method of writing the file directly to the response.  I just felt the other method wasn't clean enough so to speak.  Cleaning up the files afterwards just turned into a nightmare.  I have loaded the application to our main server and it's a whole lot faster(24gb ram, dual 4c/8t processors).  Therefore I'm not to worried about showing progress.  65,000 row write(which is the max you can do due to excel 2003 limits) only takes 10 seconds.  Most of the queries want be anywhere close to that.

Comment: Another thing Balus which came up from my boss.  Was when I wrote to the temp directory the files were available for everyone to see(if you could guess the file name).  Is there a way to implement a filter so someone couldn't directly look at the files but they were available for download.  Let me know if I need to make another topic for this.  Thanks.

Comment: You could put an autogenerated token (the temp file name?) in the session and create a `Filter` which checks the presence of this token in the current user session.